# Create an RGBA image in C++

Tags: c++, image, rgba

I have a matrix of 640x480x4 values, i.e. 640x480 pixels each with 4 channels (RGBA). I want to create a png file which shows the transparency. I have tried using opencv, but apparently transparency is not supported. What is the quickest and easiest way I can do this, I just need to save a few images?

Comment: find a library that is able to create png

Comment: @Andrew well yes, I am asking for suggestions, one that is minimally invasive and easy to use and build

Comment: When I want to find a library that implements some specification the first idea that comes in my mind is to search libspecification and usually this works. This works for png, bmp, xml, json, irc etc. because there are libpng, libbmp, libxml, libjson, libirc etc. =) And usually it is a good choice to read some examples to see will it suit for you.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious Thanks, I'm quite new to c++ not sure how library naming conventions work, also not sure what is and isn't in std

Comment: @Aly The standart c++ library is as small as it is possible and it was planned to do so. In standard c++ library there are even no threads (there is support in C++11), sockets, events, gui and all other commonly used features. Surely there are no png support in standart library. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other said, you can't easily write a PNG image file in C++ without using an external library.

[`libpng`](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) is the smallest and most portable solution, it is the official PNG reference library and is used by most of the image library to write and read PNG files. It's a fairly easy to use C library but may not be the best solution for a C++ novice.

Exemple of writing a PNG image with `libpng` :

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.png", "wb");
png_structp png_ptr = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, 0, 0, 0);
png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

/* write header */
png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, width, height,
    bit_depth, color_type, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
    PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);

png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

/* write bytes */
png_bytep * row_pointers;
<allocate row_pointers and store each row of your image in it>
png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
png_write_end(png_ptr, NULL);

/* cleanup heap allocation */
for (y=0; y<height; y++) free(row_pointers[y]);
free(row_pointers);

fclose(fp);
```

As you can see it needs quite some lines to simply initialize the writing context, and I voluntarily removed the error management which is a bit tricky with `libpng` (use of `setjmp` as instance) and definitly not suitable for a novice C programmer.

You may take a look at higher level image library such as `ImageMagick` which has a C++ API called [`Magick++`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/), here is an example of writing an image in memory to a PNG file :

```
Magick::Blob blob(data, length); 
Magick::Image image; 
image.size("640x480") 
image.magick("RGBA"); 
image.read(blob);
image.write("file.png");
```

As you can see, it's much easier with a higher level library.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from BMP images, all of the common image formats are rather complex, and you really can't just write a few lines of code and get what you want. They all have a number of elements (header, footer, etc), and typically compression in the main image sections.

You need to use a library of some sort. I've not used it directly, but code that I've compiled on my machine often seem to use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)